# I need help in getting a for loop to work

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I kind of understand what is probably happening.  The condition is obviously not being met.   Kind of like for i=0 to b where b is equal to 0 or null.
I want the number of days between two dates like 9-01-2016 and 10-31-2016.  So it should be 61 days.

```
   # dates are easily constructed and formatted
#from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import datetime

year = 2016
left_over_pill_count = input('How many pills did you have left?   ')
new_prescription = input('How many pills did you get?   ')
total_pills = int(left_over_pill_count) + int(new_prescription)
daily_pill_intake = input('How many pills do you take?    ')
starting_Month = input('Starting Month, Type 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.')
starting_Day = input('Starting Day; Type 1-31')
ending_Month = input('Ending Month, Type 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.')
ending_Day = input('Starting Day; Type 1-31')


# count number of days until next doctors appointment
date1 = datetime.date(datetime.strptime((str(year) + "-" + str(starting_Month) + "-" + str(starting_Day)), '%Y-%m-%d'))
date2 = datetime.date(datetime.strptime((str(year) + "-" + str(ending_Month) + "-" + str(ending_Day)), '%Y-%m-%d'))

#date_count = (date2 - date1)
#total_days = date_count

# fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
#fmt = '%d'
#d1 = datetime.strptime(date1, fmt)
#d2 = datetime.strptime(date2, fmt)

# print (d2-d1).days * 24 * 60

for i in range(date1.month, date2.month):
    if (date1.month == 1):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 2):
        for j in range(date1.day, 28):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 3):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 4):
        for j in range(date1.day, 30):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 5):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 6):
        for j in range(date1.day, 30):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 7):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 8):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 9):
        for j in range(date1.day, 30):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 10):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 11):
        for j in range(date1.day, 30):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    if (date1.month == 12):
        for j in range(date1.day, 31):
            total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)



#for i in range(1, int(date1.day-date2.day)):
 #   total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
  #  print(total_pills)


print("Taking " + str(daily_pill_intake) + " a day, you should have " + str(total_pills) + " left.")
```

Comment: Tell them to put in the dates like `2016-01-02`, your life will be much improved.

Comment: Also, you should consider [string formatting](http://pyformat.info), rather than simple concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code. The simple things first:

- `starting_Month` and `starting_Day`. Caps only belong in class names, e.g. `class MyClass:`.
- `datetime` has a `.date()` function that returns just the date.
- string formatting is *way* nicer than concatenation. Compare:

  ```
  '{}-{}-{}'.format(year, starting_month, starting_day)
  ```

  to what you have.
- You *have* the answer commented out - `print((d1-d2).days * 24 * 60)`. Just change that up: `print((date1-date2).days)`
- You could actually just use math here:

  ```
  pills_left = initial_pill_count - (daily_intake * number_of_days)
  ```

Putting this all together, here's how you should have written this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Just convert to int when you get the input. Also, only one space
# before input.
leftover_pill_count = int(input('How many pills do you have left? '))
new_pill_count = int(input('How many pills did you get? '))
daily_pill_intake = int(input('How many pills do you take every day? '))
# And one space before input!
start_date = input('Starting date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
end_date = input('End date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')

# Using the same format multiple places? Use a variable!
# that way you only have to change it once :) 
date_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, date_fmt)
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, date_fmt)
# `end-start`, always. Or you could use `abs(start-end)`,
# but don't do that.
total_days = (end_date-start_date).days

initial_pill_count = leftover_pill_count + new_pill_count

# Here's how the loop *should* look
loop_pills_left = initial_pill_count
for i in range(total_days):
    loop_pills_left -= daily_pill_intake
    print(loop_pills_left)

# Or you could approach it mathematically!    
math_end_count = initial_pill_count - (daily_pill_intake * total_days)

# Let's just make sure that both approaches get us the same answer, though
assert math_end_count == loop_pills_left, 'If this fails, we got our math wrong'
pills_left = loop_pills_left

# String formatting is *much* nicer than concatenation.
print('Taking {} pills per day you should have {} pills left.'
      .format(daily_pill_intake, pills_left))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Your code looks a million times better.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted with the check mark to the left `<----`